# hover in jQuery is not evaluating if statement 'equals to' comparison operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu and what I want to do is when I hover over a certain sub-menu item with text that equals let's say 'foo' and from there I want to create a flyout menu item.  The problem is if I use an if statement to evaluate that the text equals (==)  let's say 'foo' it doesn't work.  However, if I use indexOf("foo") then it works.  Is there something I need to do to make equals (==) comparison operator work inside a hover event in jQuery.  Here is some sample code to outline what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$(".static.dynamic-children:nth-child(1) li").hover(function () {
  var textValue = $(this).text();

    //Doesn't work - if statement is never evaluated
    if(textValue == "foo")
    {
      //Create flyout menu
    }

    //Works fine
    if(textValue.indexOf("foo") > -1)
    {        
      //Create flyout menu 
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you create fiddle where it is not working because I can't recreate that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is leading/trailing spaces that might be there in the text....  you can trim the text value before comparison.

```
var textValue = $(this).text().trim();//or $.trim($(this).text()) for IE < 9 support
```

---

But I would recommend doing the filtering before the hover handler is added like

```
$(".static.dynamic-children:nth-child(1) li").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'foo';
}).hover(function () {
    //Create flyout menu
});
```